# RxPermissions deny access

Tags: android, permissions, dialog, rxpermissions

I'm using `RxPermissions` to handle permissions in my Android app.
For example I have the following code inside a `button's onClickListener`

```
Disposable mDispo = new RxPermissions(this)
            .request(Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR)
            .subscribe(isAllowed -> {
                if (isAllowed) {
                    setResult(RESULT_OK);
                    finish();
                } else ExtensionsKt.showPermisionRequiredDialog(this);
            });
```

When the button is pressed it will show the following dialog.

[image]

But If I check the `Don't ask again` option and press `DENY`, the dialog will not appear again and the user is pretty much stuck until he changes the permission from the `app settings`.

For that I made a custom dialog that will be triggered when `isAllowed` is  `false` but now the problem is that the custom dialog will appear even if the user doesn't check the `Don't ask again checkbox`, just by simply pressing `DENY`.

How can I make the custom dialog appear at the next button `click` only if the user has checked the `Don't ask again` option previously?

Comment: What is lifecycle of the subscription? When does it unsubscribe?

Comment: _"the custom dialog will appear just by simply pressing DENY"_ Isn't it what you wanted?

Comment: if the `Don't ask again` checkbox is checked and you press `DENY` the next time you tap on the button, the dialog in the image will not appear anymore. That's when I want my custom dialog to show